# ScalarFunctionMultiPageEditor cannot be found by Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This is a weird situation. I am creating a plug-in which utilizes the HANA SQL Editor for Functions `.hdbscalarfunction`. It uses the dependency: `com.sap.ndb.studio.sqlscript.function`. Now, when I try accessing the class `ScalarFunctionMultiPageEditor` it is not working due to access restrictions. I then tried editing the access restrictions by allowing access to the specific package for that class. However, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I then noticed in the plugin.xml of the `com.sap.ndb.studio.sqlscript.function` is that the package for `ScalarFunctionMultiPageEditor` is not exported, so this is not visible to anyone.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plugin does not export a package then you cannot use anything in the package. The Eclipse/OSGi classloaders enforce this and you can't work around it.

Comment: That's definitely a downer! And the fact that there's no work around makes it even a double downer! Thanks @greg-499 for your reply.